# Sums of pairwise independent random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,…,X_n$ be bounded, non-constant, pairwise independent random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ , and let $Y=X_1+⋯+X_n$.

a) If $n≥2$, is there an example where $Y$ takes only 2 values ?

b) If $n=3$, is there an example where $Y$ takes only 3 values ?

Please note that the random variables are only assumed to be pairwise independent, not mutually independent.

Comment: Write your own thoughts on the questions. Hint: a) no; b) yes (think of the standard example of three pairwise, but not jointly, independent events).

Comment: @Michael, perhaps. You are right, we can make two values with this example. Anyway, too late to edit my comment. To OP: the answer to a) is YES.